# Loosing group_by information when using dplyr::do for the second time

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am running multiple models on multiple sections of my data set, similar to (but with many more models)

```
library(tidyverse)
d1 <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do(mod_linear = lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = ., x = TRUE))
d1 
# Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     cyl mod_linear 
# * <dbl> <list>     
# 1    4. <S3: lm>   
# 2    6. <S3: lm>   
# 3    8. <S3: lm>
```

I then tidy this tibble and save my parameter estimates using `tidy()` in the broom package.

I also want to calculate the standard deviation of the predictors (stored in models above as I set `x = TRUE`) to create and then compare re-scaled parameters. I can do the former of these using

```
d1 %>%
  # group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do(term = colnames(.$mod$x),
     pred_sd = apply(X = .$mod$x, MARGIN = 2, FUN = sd)) %>%
  unnest()
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#          term  pred_sd
#         <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 (Intercept)  0.00000
# 2        disp 26.87159
# 3          hp 20.93453
# 4 (Intercept)  0.00000
# 5        disp 41.56246
# 6          hp 24.26049
# 7 (Intercept)  0.00000
# 8        disp 67.77132
# 9          hp 50.97689
```

However, the result is not a grouped tibble so I end up loosing the `cyl` column to tell me which terms belong to which model. How can avoid this loss? - Adding in `group_by` again seems to throw an error.

n.b. I want avoid using purrr for at least for the first part (fitting the models) as I run different types of models and then need to reshape the results (`d1`), and I like the progress bar with `do`.

n.b. I want to work with the `$x` component of the models rather than the raw data as they have the data on correct scale (I am experimenting with different transformations of the predictors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this by `nest`ing initially and then do the `unnest`

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
      nest(-cyl) %>% 
      mutate(mod_linear = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .x, x = TRUE)),
           term  = map(mod_linear, ~ names(coef(.x))),
           pred = map(mod_linear, ~ .x$x %>%
                                       as_tibble %>% 
                                       summarise_all(sd) %>% 
                                       unlist )) %>%
   select(-data, -mod_linear) %>%
     unnest
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#    cyl term         pred
#  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#1  6.00 (Intercept)   0  
#2  6.00 disp         41.6
#3  6.00 hp           24.3
#4  4.00 (Intercept)   0  
#5  4.00 disp         26.9
#6  4.00 hp           20.9
#7  8.00 (Intercept)   0  
#8  8.00 disp         67.8
#9  8.00 hp           51.0
```

---

Or instead of calling the `map` multiple times, this can be further made compact with

```
mtcars %>% 
       group_by(cyl) %>% 
        nest(-cyl) %>% 
        mutate(mod_contents = map(data, ~ {
           mod <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = .x, x = TRUE)
           term <- names(coef(mod))
           pred <- mod$x %>%
                      as_tibble %>%
                            summarise_all(sd) %>%
                            unlist
            tibble(term, pred)        
            }
         )) %>%
      select(-data) %>%
      unnest    
# A tibble: 9 x 3
#    cyl term         pred
#  <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
#1  6.00 (Intercept)   0  
#2  6.00 disp         41.6
#3  6.00 hp           24.3
#4  4.00 (Intercept)   0  
#5  4.00 disp         26.9
#6  4.00 hp           20.9
#7  8.00 (Intercept)   0  
#8  8.00 disp         67.8
#9  8.00 hp           51.0
```

---

If we start from 'd1' (based on the OP's code)

```
d1 %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(mod_contents = map(mod_linear, ~ {

             pred <- .x$x %>%
                       as_tibble %>%
                        summarise_all(sd) %>%
                        unlist
            term <- .x %>%
                          coef %>% 
                          names 
            tibble(term, pred)                        

        }))  %>%
   select(-mod_linear) %>%
   unnest
```